# Neo4j - How to deal with aggregations on Multi dimensions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j, trying to see how to deal with aggregations on multi dimensions.
For example, I have a Person - who delivers products to different cities when ever he gets an assignment . I have Nodes as Person, Product and Cities and have relations (Delivered Products and delivered_to) between them. My Data is like below

```
P1 - [delivered Products A1, A2 ] - [to City C1]
P1 - [delivered Products  A1 ] - [to City C2] 
P1 - [delivered Products A1, A2] - [to City C2]
```

I have aggregations like below stored in my graph dbP1 - delivered 3 times Product A1

```
P1 - delivered 2 times Product A2 
P1 - delivered 1 time to city C1
P1 - delivered 2 times to city C2
```

Attached picture shows the above connections.

[image: Neo4j schema showing the above connections]

Now I want to see how many times person P1 delivered Product A1 to City C2
[P1-A1-C2]  or how many times person P1 delivered Product A1 to City C1 [P1-A1-C1] 
Trying to look the data using both product and City dimensions.

Do we have any design patterns in Graph db to handle such type of aggregations in multiple dimensions, or do we need to store the above combinations before hand itself along with the aggregations in the graph db?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main problem here is your model. Since you have a graph with a model like `(Person)-[:DELIVERED]->(:Product)-[:TO]->(:City)` there is no way to know which deliveries were made to a specific city. The relationship `[DELIVERED {times : 3}]` (for example) between a `:Person` and a `:Product` do not help to answer the questions that you are asking to the database.

A good approach that will help you is add a new node type in your model called `:Delivery`. This way you graph will looks like this:

```
(:Person)-[:MADE]->(:Delivery)
(:Delivery)-[:TO]->(:City)
(:Delivery)-[:PRODUCT]->(:Product)
```

As you can see a node `:Delivery` is related with `:Person`, `:City` and `:Product`

> Now I want to see how many times person P1 delivered Product A1 to
>   City C2 [P1-A1-C2] or how many times person P1 delivered Product A1 to
>   City C1 [P1-A1-C1] Trying to look the data using both product and City
>   dimensions.

I believe that this query will answer your question based on the proposed model:

```
MATCH (:Person {id:'P1'})-[:MADE]->(d:Delivery)-[:PRODUCT]->(:Product {id:'A1'}),
(d)-[:TO]->(:City {id:'C1'})
RETURN count(d)
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno. But I was trying to see, if i have lakhs of deliveries happening each day, i would be storing the complete information like the transactional data again in the Graph db. The data would grow exponentially. I am trying to see my Graph db as aggregated database, where i want to see once a month, how many delivered product A1 to city C1 etc. In my real time data, i would have multiple dimensions to this delivery.

Comment: Hello. I believe [this link](http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/) can help you.

Comment: Thanks Bruno.. this is very good link to know about graph versioning. Here also.. the data is not stored at sale id level.. and also has only one dimension ''product' to the sale.